# Django: Count objects in a particular month

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-aggregation

I have this model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
   city = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
   added_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

I want to create a template/view that has a table of months and the number of people added that month (ie, 5 in january, 10 in february, 8 in march, etc.). I have a similar table for all the people from a each city using:

```
cities = Patient.objects.values('city').annotate(city_count=Count('city')).order_by('-city_count')
```

I don't know how to do that for my months table. I could filter for a particular month, then count all. But then I'd need to run that through a loop over every month, which would be multiple database hits. I don't want to do that.

Is there a way to do this without writing sql and just using django's api?

Comment: Have you considered pulling them all, working on it in Python? It's only one DB hit, but a big one

Comment: I guess I could try that but I wonder if there is a more elegant way to use django to help me with this, or if not, to allow the db query to do it for me; that seems more appropriate to me.

Answer (score 0):

Its a very old thread, but i guess I'll answer in case someone else ended up here looking for a solution.
The solution is for Django 1.10+ using the ExtractMonth function, for more detail visit official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#extract)

First you have to import ExtractMonth, like

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractMonth
```

Then using your Persons model, the code will be like this

```
personsMonthlyData = Person.objects.annotate(month=ExtractMonth('added_date')).values('month').annotate(count=Count('id')).order_by('month')
```

personsMonthlyData will output something like this

```
[{month: 1, count: 3}, {month: 2: count: 1}]
```

where month represent the month number e.g. 1 for January and 2 for February and the count against each month is assigned to the count item.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

The fact that most DBs have such a perfect way of doing this with a `GROUP BY` query that has no analog in Django AFAIK would lead me to drop into SQL to do this. I did a google search for "django sql" and turned up this post by Doug Hellman on this exact problem: http://blog.doughellmann.com/2007/12/using-raw-sql-in-django.html. I would use that as a starting point for getting your month counts into Django.